# ¿Como hago para usar una url encriptada?

Tags: url, urlencoding, encoding

tengo una duda. Tengo que pasar información por la url, pero no quiero que se vea, así que estoy viendo como hacer que un link (Ej. "cliente/todosillas/sillon-silla_braun-34763.php") se encubra (Ej. "Y2xpZW50ZS90b2Rvc2lsbGFzL3NpbGxvbi1zaWxsYV9icmF1bi0zNDc2My5waHA=
"), porque no quiero que se vea.
Se que hay otras formas de para enviar información, pero tengo que hacerlo de esta forma, ya que me lo pidieron :(.

Gracias y sepan disculpar si no soy claro.

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías insertar un ejemplo del código que estás usando?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta eso, deberías crear un **.htaccess** y configurarlo algo así:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cliente/(.*) /receptor.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Este código hará que cuando entren en **tudominio.com/cliente/Y2xpZW50ZS90b2Rvc2lsbGFzL3NpbGxvbi1zaWxsYV9icmF1bi0zNDc2My5waHA=**

Envíe la información a un archivo php que en este caso se llama **receptor.php**, luego con ese archivo consultas en la base de datos en una tabla si existe la variable que viene por el **GET['id']** y si encuentra resultado haces la lógica que quieras.

Puedes usar Hash para crear ese tipo de string encriptado: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.hash.php

Es una manera de hacerlo, hay varias formas, espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias! No sabia como buscar lo que necesitaba. Es eso mismo que vos comentas.